# Using igraph in R find unique edges in one graph missing from another graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have created two undirected igraph with the following edges

graph1 => `A--A`,`A--B`and`A--C`

graph2 => `B--A`,`C--D`,`D--E`and`A--C`

```
library(igraph)
my_data = data.frame(id1=c("A","A","A","B","C","A","D"),id2=c("A","B","C","A","D","C","E"))
graph1 = graph.data.frame(my_data[1:3,],directed=F)
graph2 = graph.data.frame(my_data[4:7,],directed=F)
```

I want to find edges unique to graph2. Therefore, the output should be like:

```
# C--D D--E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
get.edgelist(graph2-graph1)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "C"  "D" 
# [2,] "D"  "E"
```

or, with regards to your edit:

```
E(graph2-graph1)
# + 2/2 edges (vertex names):
# [1] C--D D--E
```

Comment: Perfect. I didnt know we could subtract graphs like that. Thank you..!!